# How to remove every instance of a column in a data frame that doesn't have exactly two words?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
     species        |    BIN      |    collectors  |  country      | grade
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tilapia guineensis  |BOLD:AAL5979 |    C.D. Nwani  |     Nigeria   | NA
Tilapia             |BOLD:AAB9042 |    C.D. Nwani  |     Nigeria   | NA
Fundulus rubrifrons |BOLD:AAI7245 |  John Donavan  |  United States| NA
Eutrigla gurnardus  |BOLD:AAC0262 |Hermann Neumann |    North Sea  | NA
Sprattus            |BOLD:AAE9187 |Hermann Neumann |    North Sea  | NA
Gadus morhua        |BOLD:ACF1143 |Hermann Neumann |    North Sea  | NA
Tilapia zillii      |BOLD:AAB9042 |     C.D. Nwani |      Nigeria  | NA
Gadus               |BOLD:ACF1169 |   Angela Cicia |  United States| NA
```

Basically some of the species names are incomplete and only have one word. I want to remove every instance of the data frame in which the species name doesn't have exactly two words, is there a simple way to do it ?

In the case of the first data frame I presented, I would expect something like this:

```
   species          |    BIN      |    collectors  |  country      | grade
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tilapia guineensis  |BOLD:AAL5979 |    C.D. Nwani  |     Nigeria   | NA
Fundulus rubrifrons |BOLD:AAI7245 |  John Donavan  |  United States| NA
Eutrigla gurnardus  |BOLD:AAC0262 |Hermann Neumann |    North Sea  | NA
Gadus morhua        |BOLD:ACF1143 |Hermann Neumann |    North Sea  | NA
Tilapia zillii      |BOLD:AAB9042 |     C.D. Nwani |      Nigeria  | NA
```

Thank you in advance for any responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` and `lengths` in Base R:

```
subset(DF, lengths(strsplit(species, " ")) == 2)
```

**Output:**

```
              species          BIN      collectors       country grade
1  Tilapia guineensis BOLD:AAL5979      C.D. Nwani       Nigeria    NA
3 Fundulus rubrifrons BOLD:AAI7245    John Donavan United States    NA
4  Eutrigla gurnardus BOLD:AAC0262 Hermann Neumann     North Sea    NA
6        Gadus morhua BOLD:ACF1143 Hermann Neumann     North Sea    NA
7      Tilapia zillii BOLD:AAB9042      C.D. Nwani       Nigeria    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, use the indicated regular expression to `grep` for `species` with two (or more) words.  If it must be exactly two words use `^\\S+ \\S+$` instead.  No packages are used.

```
subset(DF, grepl("\\S+ \\S+", species))
```

giving:

```
              species          BIN      collectors       country grade
1  Tilapia guineensis BOLD:AAL5979      C.D. Nwani       Nigeria    NA
3 Fundulus rubrifrons BOLD:AAI7245    John Donavan United States    NA
4  Eutrigla gurnardus BOLD:AAC0262 Hermann Neumann     North Sea    NA
6        Gadus morhua BOLD:ACF1143 Hermann Neumann     North Sea    NA
7      Tilapia zillii BOLD:AAB9042      C.D. Nwani       Nigeria    NA
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "     species        |    BIN      |    collectors  |  country      | grade
Tilapia guineensis  |BOLD:AAL5979 |    C.D. Nwani  |     Nigeria   | NA
Tilapia             |BOLD:AAB9042 |    C.D. Nwani  |     Nigeria   | NA
Fundulus rubrifrons |BOLD:AAI7245 |  John Donavan  |  United States| NA
Eutrigla gurnardus  |BOLD:AAC0262 |Hermann Neumann |    North Sea  | NA
Sprattus            |BOLD:AAE9187 |Hermann Neumann |    North Sea  | NA
Gadus morhua        |BOLD:ACF1143 |Hermann Neumann |    North Sea  | NA
Tilapia zillii      |BOLD:AAB9042 |     C.D. Nwani |      Nigeria  | NA
Gadus               |BOLD:ACF1169 |   Angela Cicia |  United States| NA"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = "|", strip.white = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_count` to count the number of words in the 'species' and filter those rows have more than one word

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    filter(str_count(species, "\\w+") == 2)
#              species          BIN      collectors       country grade
#1  Tilapia guineensis BOLD:AAL5979      C.D. Nwani       Nigeria    NA
#2 Fundulus rubrifrons BOLD:AAI7245    John Donavan United States    NA
#3  Eutrigla gurnardus BOLD:AAC0262 Hermann Neumann     North Sea    NA
#4        Gadus morhua BOLD:ACF1143 Hermann Neumann     North Sea    NA
#5      Tilapia zillii BOLD:AAB9042      C.D. Nwani       Nigeria    NA
```

---

Or with `base R` using `gregexpr` and `lengths`

```
subset(df1, lengths(gregexpr("\\w+", species)) == 2)
```